# Debian package bug on squeeze?

Tags: cmake, debian, packaging, deb, cpack

My hand-made debian package wont install if i build it on Squeeze (well, a squeezechroot)?
If i built it on a wheezy box though it builds installable packages.

Note that it *builds* fine in either case. Im generating the debian packages using CMake/CPack.

The error message i get is:

```
user@buildbox:/builddir/packagename# dpkg -i packagename_1.0.3.deb
(Reading database ... 35116 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking packagename (from packagename_1.0.3.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing packagename_1.0.3.deb (--install):
 unable to create `/usr/share/packagename/builddir/mixer_devices.txt.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/share/packagename/builddir/mixer_devices.txt'): No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packagename_1.0.3.deb
```

Comment: Do you really want to create `/usr/share/packagename/builddir/mixer_devices.txt` as part of installing the package? "builddir" sounds like something that shouldn't be installed.

Comment: Ooh, this is a very good point. In my cPack file (which is generating these packages), its install target is correctly set to /use/share/package name/mixer_devices.txt.

Comment: No more ideas? I'm gonna diff the squeeze built version and the wheezy built one and see what's different.

Comment: I kinda expected a yes or no answer to my question. If you want it packaged, you need to add the dir to `debian/dirs`. If not, figure out why it's being included in the `debian/tmp` and get it out of there.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that `mixer_devices` is not contained within the created deb file for some reason?

Just do an `ar x packagename_1.0.3.deb` and see what the tar file contains.